# How to scroll an image over fixed content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm building a Shopify site, and want an overlay image to cover the top content when you land on the website. Then when you scroll, this overlay image moves up and off the screen revealing the website.

I found some javascript that does this, but the main website scrolls with the overlay image. Is there a way to have it scroll on its own and not scroll the content behind?

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('overlay-container');
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var scrollArea = 1000 - windowHeight;
var square1 = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-background-image')[0];
// var square2 = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-logo')[1];

// update position of square 1 and square 2 when scroll event fires.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollTop;
  var scrollPercent = scrollTop / scrollArea || 0;

  square1.style.bottom = -100 * (1 - scrollPercent * 1.5) + 'vh';
  //   square2.style.top = 800 - scrollPercent*window.innerHeight*0.6 + 'px';
});


// Global variable to control the scrolling behavior
const step = 30; // For each 30px, change an image
function trackScrollPosition() {
  const y = window.scrollY;
  const label = Math.min(Math.floor(y / 30) + 1, 20);
  const imageToUse = fruitImages[label];
  // Change the background image
  $('.image-container').css('background-image', `url('${imageToUse}')`);
}
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(window).scroll(() => {
    trackScrollPosition();
  })
})
```

```css
.overlay-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.overlay-background-image {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay-container">
  <div class="overlay-background-image">
    <img style="height: 100vh;" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/2225/7886/files/01_-_Landing_Page.png?v=1636020266" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We made you a snippet. There are some missing array

Comment: I did not do ANYTHING in the snippet. I converted YOUR code to a snippet - why would I answer inside your question?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your initial comment. This is the first time I'm using Stack Overflow and I didn't realise that was what you had done. Apologies.

Comment: just add the css styling "position:sticky;" to the page content underneath the image

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I misread the question.

Original answer:

This will automatically scroll the image offscreen once the page is loaded. (Not what the question wanted)

I'd recommend using css rather than JavaScript for this.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.overlay-background-image {
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: shop_reveal;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: calc(100vh * 1440/767);
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0608/2225/7886/files/01_-_Landing_Page.png?v=1636020266');
}

@keyframes shop_reveal {
  from {
    bottom: 0px
  }
  to {
    bottom: 100vh
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay-container">
  <div class="overlay-background-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited answer:
This will scroll the image along with the scrollbar.

````html
    <div class="overlay-container">
      <div class="overlay-background-image">
      </div>
    </div>```

<!-- end snippet -->

pagebox is the content that will be revealed when the user scrolls the page.

<!-- language: lang-css -->
```#pagebox {
position: absolute;
}```
<!-- end snippet -->

Give pagebox absolute positioning so that it's position can be set in JavaScript and it doesn't push the image.

<!-- language: lang-javascript -->
```var container = document.getElementById('overlay-container');
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
var scrollArea = 1000 - windowHeight;
var square1 = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-background-image')[0];
// var square2 = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay-logo')[1];

var p = document.getElementById("pagebox");

// update position of square 1 and square 2 when scroll event fires.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || window.scrollTop;
  var scrollPercent = scrollTop / scrollArea || 0;

  square1.style.bottom = p.style.marginTop = -100 * (1 - scrollPercent * 1.5) + 'vh';
  //   square2.style.top = 800 - scrollPercent*window.innerHeight*0.6 + 'px';
});```

<!-- end snippet -->

As the page is scrolled. The image overlay is moved up by this code. However the normal functioning of the scrolling is still in effect so the rest of the page moves up with it. In order to counteract this. The position of the content underneath the image is moved down by the amount the page is scrolled. 

(simply using position:sticky would prevent the content underneath the page from exceeding the height of the window so can't be used)
````

Comment: Yes good idea, thanks for the above. The main idea is I want exactly what you have happening with the above animation, but as a user is scrolling.
As a compromise, instead of having it move when you scroll maybe I should just trigger the CSS animation on scroll instead.

Comment: If they scrolled back up. Would you want it to move back onto the screen? Also would there be other content on the page or would the entire page be underneath the image?

Comment: No, I'd only want it to show when they land on the page, not when they scroll back up. It would be the entire homepage page underneath the image, so I wanted the image to scroll up independently of the homepage underneath.

Comment: Try offsetting the content underneath the image overlay by the amount the page is scrolled. One way to do this would be to wrap the page underneath the image in a div then give it position:absolute. Then in your function set the marginTop of the wrapping div to the same as square1.style.bottom. Does this give the desired effect?

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you.

Comment: mplungjan can you edit my updated answe again. I'm not sure what's going on. Thanks